# How to stop receive method when Websocket does not send a response within X amount of time (java)

Tags: java, websocket

I am currently trying to speed up some automation tests on a Websocket, and the only way I can cut time is to be able to stop a receive method if no response has been received from the websocket in X amount of time. Currently as it is implemented, my test sends a message through the Websocket and gets a response if a certain ACK parameter is set to true and does not get a response if it is set to false. When the ACK parameter is set to false, my tests are running for about 30 seconds each waiting on a server ping that happens every thirty seconds.

Here is my Websocket implementation:

```
 /**
  * The MIT License
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2009 Adam MacBeth
  *
  * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
  * of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
  * in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
  * to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
  * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
  * furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
  *
  * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
  * all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
  * 
  * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
  * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
  * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
  * AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
  * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
  * OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
  * THE SOFTWARE.
  */
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.io.OutputStream;
 import java.net.Socket;
 import java.net.URI;
 import java.util.HashMap;
 import java.util.Map.Entry;

 import javax.net.SocketFactory;
 import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

 /**
 * An implementation of a WebSocket protocol client.
 */
 public class WebSocket {

 /** The URL. */
 private URI mUrl;

 /** The socket. */
 private Socket mSocket;

 /** Whether the handshake is complete. */
 private boolean mHandshakeComplete;

 /** The socket input stream. */
 private InputStream mInput;

 /** The socket mOutput stream. */
 private OutputStream mOutput;

 /** The external headers. */
 private HashMap<String, String> mHeaders; 

 /**
 * Creates a new WebSocket targeting the specified URL.
 * @param url The URL for the socket.
 */
 public WebSocket(URI url) {
    mUrl = url;

    String protocol = mUrl.getScheme();
    if (!protocol.equals("ws") && !protocol.equals("wss")) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported protocol: " + protocol);
    }
 }

 /**
 * Sets extra headers to be sent.
 * @param headers A hash of header name-values.
 */
 public void setHeaders(HashMap<String, String> headers) {
    mHeaders = headers;
 }

 /**
 * Returns the underlying socket;
 */
 public Socket getSocket() {
    return mSocket;
 }

 /**
 * Establishes the connection.
 */
 public void connect() throws java.io.IOException {
    String host = mUrl.getHost();
    String path = mUrl.getPath();
    if (path.equals("")) {
        path = "/";
    }

    String query = mUrl.getQuery();
    if (query != null) {
        path = path + "?" + query;
    }

    String origin = "http://" + host;

    mSocket = createSocket();
    int port = mSocket.getPort();
    if (port != 80) {
        host = host + ":" + port;
    }

    mOutput = mSocket.getOutputStream();
    StringBuffer extraHeaders = new StringBuffer();
    if (mHeaders != null) {
        for (Entry<String, String> entry : mHeaders.entrySet()) {
            extraHeaders.append(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue() + "\r\n");             
        }
    }

    String request = "GET "+path+" HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
                     "Upgrade: WebSocket\r\n" +
                     "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" +
                     "Host: "+host+"\r\n" +
                     "Origin: "+origin+"\r\n" +
                     extraHeaders.toString() +
                     "\r\n";
    mOutput.write(request.getBytes());
    mOutput.flush();

    mInput = mSocket.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mInput));
    String header = reader.readLine();
    if (!header.equals("HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake")) {
        throw new IOException("Invalid handshake response");
    }

    header = reader.readLine();
    if (!header.equals("Upgrade: WebSocket")) {
        throw new IOException("Invalid handshake response");
    }

    header = reader.readLine();
    if (!header.equals("Connection: Upgrade")) {
        throw new IOException("Invalid handshake response");
    }

    do {
        header = reader.readLine();
    } while (!header.equals(""));

    mHandshakeComplete = true;
 }

 private Socket createSocket() throws java.io.IOException {
    String scheme = mUrl.getScheme();
    String host = mUrl.getHost();

    int port = mUrl.getPort();
    if (port == -1) {
        if (scheme.equals("wss")) {
            port = 443;
        } else if (scheme.equals("ws")) {
            port = 80;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported scheme");
        }
    }

    if (scheme.equals("wss")) {
        SocketFactory factory = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        return factory.createSocket(host, port);
     } else {
         return new Socket(host, port);
     }
 }

  /**
  * Sends the specified string as a data frame.
  * @param str The string to send.
  * @throws java.io.IOException
  */
  public void send(String str) throws java.io.IOException {
    if (!mHandshakeComplete) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Handshake not complete");
    }

    mOutput.write(0x00);
    mOutput.write(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    mOutput.write(0xff);
    mOutput.flush();
 }

 /**
 * Receives the next data frame.
 * @return The received data.
 * @throws java.io.IOException
 */
 public String recv() throws java.io.IOException {      
    if (!mHandshakeComplete) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Handshake not complete");
    }
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

        int b = mInput.read();
        if ((b & 0x80) == 0x80) {
            // Skip data frame
            int len = 0;
            do {
                b = mInput.read() & 0x7f;
                len = len * 128 + b;
            } while ((b & 0x80) != 0x80);

            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                mInput.read();
            }
        }

        while (true) {
            b = mInput.read();
            if (b == 0xff) {
                break;
            }

            buf.append((char)b);            
        }
        return new String(buf.toString().getBytes(), "UTF8");
}

/**
 * Closes the socket.
 * @throws java.io.IOException
 */
public void close() throws java.io.IOException {
    mInput.close();
    mOutput.close();
    mSocket.close();
}
}
```

And here is the receive method I want to be able to speed up:

```
public String recv() throws java.io.IOException {       
    if (!mHandshakeComplete) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Handshake not complete");
    }
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

        int b = mInput.read();
        if ((b & 0x80) == 0x80) {
            // Skip data frame
            int len = 0;
            do {
                b = mInput.read() & 0x7f;
                len = len * 128 + b;
            } while ((b & 0x80) != 0x80);

            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                mInput.read();
            }
        }

        while (true) {
            b = mInput.read();
            if (b == 0xff) {
                break;
            }

            buf.append((char)b);            
        }
        return new String(buf.toString().getBytes(), "UTF8");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the setSoTimeout(int timeout); function on your socket object. when the time expires a SocketTimeoutException is thrown.

here is the oracle api link: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29)

Comment: Wow, can't believe i missed this. Thank you!